# How does the flash become available through the request?

Tags: scala, playframework, implicit

I have a controller with an action:

```
def index = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(views.html.index(MyModel.all)
}
```

And an index view with the following parameters:

```
@(my_models : List[MyModel])(implicit flash : Flash)
```

It seems as though I need to have both of these implicits in order to have access to the flash without passing it around explicitly. This is how I think the flash implicit works:
If the template is called without an explicit flash parameter, then the compiler will look for a Flash marked implicit in the scope in which the view function was called. Where does this flash come from? The request is marked implicit, but it is not a Flash.  I know that the request has a flash member, but I don't see how the view would gain access to this based on my understanding of implicits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method `index` is a part of some class, that extends [`Controller`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Controller), so all methods of `Controller` are in scope.

There is implicit method `flash` in `Controller`:

```
 implicit def flash (implicit request: RequestHeader): Flash
```

So if you have implicit `RequestHeader` in scope it can be converter to `Flash` implicitly.
`